# Don't have access from activity to adapter method recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I found [this](https://www.journaldev.com/23164/android-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-undo) example of adding swipe delete at recyclerview. But I  can't see method of removing items at recyclerview adapter:

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

I decided that I have to add `static` but I didn't help. Maybe someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Add entire adapter code and snippet of `removeItem` method usage in activity, please

Comment: What do you mean? you cannot find remove method implementation? or removeItem() usage? I found the usage of removeItem() in mainActivity in the example

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn, I can't use removeitem method at the activity

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko please provide your adapter and activity code

Comment: I have to add all adapter and activity code, or only some parts of it?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko whole code

Comment: I can use removeitem method at any place, but don't at swipedelete class

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn, https://pastebin.com/wKzzXpLb - activity code, https://pastebin.com/yZNPdhxi - adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not your custom adapter:

```
 adapter = new ListAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity(), type);
```

I guess you are using ListAdapter Class instead of your custom adapter. Could change (refactor) your ListAdapter class using another name like customAdapter for example?

Comment: I have renamed it, but I don't have access because removeItem isn't static

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko let me chk again. if it is public and you make an object of your adapter you can use it.it shouldn't be static necessarily.

Comment: I think similarly, but I see that I can't get access anyway :(

Comment: Do you have access to it in onCreateView() where you make adapter object? @AndrewGoroshko

Comment: you defined your adapter variable like this:   private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
please define it like this :
private yourCustomAdaptername adapter ;

Answer (score 2):

The `removeItem(int position)` is method of adapter, not activity, so try `mAdapter.removeItem(..)` inside Activity code